# How can I do a mechanize multisearch?

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I am wondering is it possible to do multiple mechanize queries using an array? the following code minus the array works fine with a single but not multiple queries.

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new

#User Agent masking
agent.user_agent_alias = 'Windows Mozilla'

#Array of keywords to search
search = Array.new

search << 'TAICHI 21'
search << 'S56CA'

#Take our search array, insert it into a query
agent.get("http://www.asus.com/Search/?SearchKey=#{search}")

#This handles the url
File.open("results.txt","w") do |f|
    PP.pp(page.links.find_all{|l| l.text =~ /#{search}/i},f)
end
```

**2nd Attempt**

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new

#User Agent masking
agent.user_agent_alias = 'Windows Mozilla'

#Array of keywords to search
search = [ 'S56CA', 'TAICHI 21' ]

#Take our search array, insert it into a query
agent.get("http://www.asus.com/Search/?SearchKey=#{search}")

File.open("results.txt","w") 

#This handles the url
search.each do |f|
    results.txt << PP.pp(page.links.find_all{|l| l.text =~ /#{search}/i},f)
end
```

Comment: How would you do the same search from the browser? The search bar on the http://www.asus.com/ site doesn't seem to support search for multiple items. There doesn't seem to be a way to search for both 'TAICHI 21' & 'S56CA' at the same time.

Comment: Yes I was looking to search a result one at a time, write that result to results.txt

Answer (score 0):

When you search for `S56CA` with http://www.asus.com/Search/?SearchKey=S56CA, the site redirects to http://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/S56CA/ page. This is unlike when searched for `TAICHI 21` which stays on the results page.

Each of these is a different behavior, so the code should handle each case differently.

I modified your original code to include mechanize logging as follows:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'mechanize'

# Logging 
require 'logger'

mechanize_logger = Logger.new('mechanize.log')
mechanize_logger.level = Logger::INFO

agent = Mechanize.new
agent.log = mechanize_logger

#User Agent masking
agent.user_agent_alias = 'Windows Mozilla'

search_terms = [ 'S56CA', 'TAICHI 21' ]
results_file = File.open( 'results.txt', 'w' )

#Take our search array, insert it into a query
search_terms.each do |search|
  page = agent.get("http://www.asus.com/Search/?SearchKey=#{search}")
  links =  page.links.find_all{ |l| l.text =~ /#{search}/i}
  links.each { |links_text| results_file.write( "#{links_text}\n" ) }
end 
results_file.close
```

When this code is run, the output of the program is just `ASUS TAICHI 21` which is written to `results.txt`.

The `mechanize.log` file has the following content, showing the difference between the two searches:

```
$ more mechanize.log 
I, [2013-01-30T17:49:49.036790 #2142]  INFO -- : Net::HTTP::Get: /Search/?SearchKey=S56CA
I, [2013-01-30T17:49:53.528281 #2142]  INFO -- : status: Net::HTTPFound 1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
I, [2013-01-30T17:49:53.529388 #2142]  INFO -- : follow redirect to: /Notebooks_Ultrabooks/S56CA/
I, [2013-01-30T17:49:53.530106 #2142]  INFO -- : Net::HTTP::Get: /Notebooks_Ultrabooks/S56CA/
I, [2013-01-30T17:49:53.939353 #2142]  INFO -- : status: Net::HTTPOK 1.1 200 OK
I, [2013-01-30T17:49:54.800423 #2142]  INFO -- : Net::HTTP::Get: /Search/?SearchKey=TAICHI%2021
I, [2013-01-30T17:49:55.269454 #2142]  INFO -- : status: Net::HTTPOK 1.1 200 OK
```

Since the search page has the content `Did you mean to search for`, you can use that to differentiate the behavior in your code.

Comment: No problem, for the 'S56CA' result I am looking to get to http://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/S56CA/ anyway so I can grab its specs. the "TAICHI 21" I just have to tell mechanize to follow the link.

Comment: OK; so with that you are able to make multiple queries with mechanize, right? Or is any part of your question not answered yet?

Comment: Ok I think my brain is just melting, I tried grabbing the links but now with the file redirection from original code and I just can't get the syntax correct :(

Comment: :-) Looks like you have difficulty working with arrays. Take a look at the code example in my answer.

Comment: I have basic ruby experience but I like to learn by doing and trial and error with the help of those who know best, I need mechanize to help me with my inventory work.

Comment: Your troubles is with arrays, and not with mechanize. When you are looping with `search.each do |f|` each of the items are available as a value of `f`; you shouldn't be referring to `search` within the loop.

Comment: Ok how can I get my loop to go into the results.txt file?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23707/discussion-between-prakash-murthy-and-ninja2k)